# Moving a <tag> to inside? only the ending tag not the whole <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to figure out if it is possible to move the

> div tag>

so let's say i have  paragraph and below it is a image something like this
[image]

is what i want to know if it's possible, and if it is, please can anyone tell me how using jquery or javascript.

Comment: Yes, it's indirectly possible. Can you please post the code that you tried?

Comment: please show how to do it @JoshCrozier

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can move an image out of a div, but you cannot move the end of the div itself. That's because the HTML document is translated to an in-memory object structure, which has no notion of closing tags. It does have nodes with a parent-child relation, so you could change the image from being a child of the div to being a sibling of the div.

Comment: aww~, so it's not how sad. anyway, can you show me hot to move image out of the div? @GolezTrol

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle , http://jsbin.com/qunece/edit?html,js,output

You can copy the contents of one and append it to the other

```
var html = $('#id2').html();
$('#id1').append(html);
$('#id2').remove();
```

Comment: yes it is, but i'm looking only for ending tag to move not the whole div tag

Comment: can you show us the code

Comment: whatever tag you want to move, select that tag, copy it's html, append it where you want. and the delete the actual